# Change in integration order not allowed?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I am working on the Thomson dipole where I need to evaluate a double integral. However, if I do the angular part first the integral diverges. Doing the radial part first apparently gives a finite value, showing the total angular momentum of the dipole field is independent of the separation distance of the electrical and magnetic charge.

Thus in general, how can one be sure change in order is allowed and what does it mean if the integral gives two different values depending on the order? Especially here in a physical situation.

The integral is $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\pi }\frac{s\sin^{3}(\theta )}{(1+s^2-2s\cos(\theta ))^{3/2}}\,\mathrm{d}\theta\,\mathrm{d}s$$

Comment: Pls, share the integral with us.

Comment: I think you're after [Fubinis theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem).

Comment: What are the variables of integration? If $\theta$ is a variable, then it must not appear as a limit of the inner integral. Here you seem to be integrating over a sector of the plane. Is that what you were after?

Comment: Could you describe the integral in cartesian coordinates, please? I suspect something went wrong when you converted to polar.

Comment: Im so sorry it should have been pi as limit. This is the problematic integral coming from the integral of all of space, more precisely the integral of the position vector crossed with the EM momentum density vector field.

Comment: Essentially this is integrating over all of space in spherical polars, the phi part has been omitted as it is a constant (system is rotation invariant in phi)

Comment: Did you mean to append $\,\mathrm{d}\theta\,\mathrm{d}s$ ?

Comment: oh yes, sorry for that i am such a latex newbie :/

Comment: If you showed the attempt that diverged, perhaps we could be of more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that
$$
\begin{align}
\left(1+s^2-2s\cos(\theta)\right)^{3/2}
&=\left((1-s\cos(\theta))^2+(s\sin(\theta))^2\right)^{3/2}\\[3pt]
&\ge s^3\sin^3(\theta)\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
Furthermore,
$$
\begin{align}
\left(1+s^2-2s\cos(\theta)\right)^{3/2}
&=\left((1-s)^2+2s(1-\cos(\theta))\right)^{3/2}\\[3pt]
&\ge|1-s|^3\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
&\int_0^\infty\int_0^\pi\frac{s\sin^3(\theta)}{(1+s^2-2s\cos(\theta))^{3/2}}\,\mathrm{d}\theta\,\mathrm{d}s\\[3pt]
&\le\int_{1/2}^\infty\int_0^\pi\frac{s}{s^3}\,\mathrm{d}\theta\,\mathrm{d}s
+\int_0^{1/2}\int_0^\pi\frac{s\sin^3(\theta)}{(1-s)^3}\,\mathrm{d}\theta\,\mathrm{d}s\\[3pt]
&=2\pi+\tfrac43\cdot\tfrac12\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
First, the integrand is non-negative, so [Fubini's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) says the integral should be independent of the order of integration. Furthermore, $(3)$ gives an upper bound for the integral. Check your work on the order of integration that diverges.

Comment: hey I solved it, wasn't careful with the positive roots and splitting the the integral up into two parts. Thanks!